# Unifying localhost dev api server access for expo app across Android, IOS, and web?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm setting up a simple React Native learning app for several students on Expo, that also talks to an API server the student is learning to code.

The student's API server is run via `node server.js`, and serves on `localhost:3000` on the student's machine.  It has nothing to do with expo.

I want students to be able to run their app via any of `expo start --android`, `expo start --ios`, or `expo start --web`, on the same machine that runs their API server.  Each student runs from home on a different home wifi network, and doesn't necessarily know the ins and outs of ip addresses or networking.

When using `expo start --web`, we get CORS exceptions, unless we use the custom `webpack.config.js` work around (first create `webpack.config.js` via https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-webpack/, then put this in `webpack.config.js`):

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function(env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
  if (config.mode === 'development') {
    config.devServer.proxy = {
      '/**': {
        target: {
          host: 'localhost',
          protocol: 'http:',
          port: 3000,
        },
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: 'info',
      },
    };
  }
  return config;
};
```

This is great, because we can make api calls to `./end/point` without knowing the student's ip address, and the webpack devServer launched by expo-cli effectively proxies around to `http://localhost:3000/end/point` on the student's development machine.

Meanwhile, for iOS and Android, I've found this snippet:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";
const { manifest } = Constants;
const SERVER_URL = "http://"+manifest.debuggerHost.split(`:`).shift().concat(`:3000`)+"/";
```

and then using `SERVER_URL` when using `fetch()`.

But, we're missing a unified solution that works agnostic of which environment we're in (web, ios, or android).  The webpack proxy only appears to be on and work when using the expo web client (expo-cli doesn't launch webpack for ios or android), and the 2nd option (A) doesn't work out of the box on web and (B) would trigger a CORS exception anyway.

How can I elegantly write one bit of code, or otherwise set up the project for the students, so that (A) they don't need to know their dev machine's ip address, or what that means and (B) it will work regardless of whether they're in the web, android, or ios expo client?

Answer (score 1):

Don't like this as an answer and would prefer someone who knows better to point out better, but this is what I ended up using that seems to work, at least in development:

```
// Some chatter that Contants.manifest needs to come from a different package?
import Constants from "expo-constants";
const { manifest } = Constants;

const SERVER_URL = (() => {
  // TODO - put a "prod" api server somewhere

  // Android / IOS - no CORS issue.
  if (!!manifest.debuggerHost) {
    return "http://"+manifest.debuggerHost.split(`:`).shift().concat(`:3000/`);
  } 
  // Expo Web client, making use of webpack.config.js (see original question) for devServer proxy.
  else {
    return "./";
  }
})();

...
fetch(SERVER_URL + 'some_endpoint/').then(...)
```